# Changing owner of subsite/teamsite

Tags: office-365, central-administration

So first off, I'm not sure if this can be answered here.

Our whole O365, right now has an "owners" account - how do I add another owner, so that mine and the account that first bought O365 have equal rights?

Second, as of now this owner also "owns" all subsite/teamsites, because I used this account to make them all - how do I change the owner of these subsites?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give a new account or existing account full administrative rights on the o365 subscription(similar rights to the original account who created the subscription) check this  [o365 Support Article](https://support.office.com/en-US/client/results?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=O365ENTADMIN&version=15&ver=15&services=INTUNE_O365%2COFFICESUBSCRIPTION%2CMCOSTANDARD%2CEXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE%2CSHAREPOINTWAC_DEVELOPER%2CSHAREPOINT_S_DEVELOPER&HelpID=O365E_AssignAdminRoles)